# Effective Policy Viewer for Ent Lib 4

Tags: .net, enterprise-library, aop, policy-injection

I can't find the effective policy viewer tool for enterprise library 4.  All the links I find on the net point to source I have to compile against entlib 3 dll's.

Does anyone know where I can find the updated tool? Or does the old one work and can someone provide the binaries?

Answer (score 1):

Efective Policy Viewer for EntLib 3.0 will work with EntLib 4.x as stated here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd140028.aspx

The stand-alone solution can be downloaded from here:
http://www.codeplex.com/entlib/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2899